# How can we pass url parameter to rdl file?

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a requirement to show the static text of my report in different language.

**Steps  that I am following:**

1. Create a url with query string parameter with CultureInfo.
   http://localhost/Report.aspx?UserId=5?CultureInfo=cs-CZ?ReportsPath=UserReport/New
2. Now I want to fetch this CultureInfo=cs-CZ in my rdl file.
3. On the basis of my CultureInfo I will do the dynamic change with IIF or SWITCH

**Problem I am getting:**

How to fetch the CultureInfo value in my rdl file?
Or,How can I print this value in any of the textbox to check what is passed to it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I have a requirement to show the static text of my report in different language.

Steps  that I am following:
1. Create a url with query string parameter with CultureInfo.
http://localhost/Report.aspx?UserId=5?CultureInfo=cs-CZ?ReportsPath=UserReport/New

2. Now I want to fetch this CultureInfo=cs-CZ in my rdl file.
3. On the basis of my CultureInfo I will do the dynamic change with IIF or SWITCH

Problem I am getting:

How to fetch the CultureInfo value in my rdl file?
Or,How can I print this value in any of the textbox to check what is passed to it?